# How to make the border of the input go in front of parent div?

Tags: html, css

I need the div of the input take over the div of the datepicker and have 1 same border which is the div of the input.

Here is a pen to the code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pGeXwv

Html:

```
<div class="datePickerWrapper"><input type="text" id="datepicker"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#datepicker {
        border: 1px solid #717171;
        border-radius: 5px;
        font-weight: 400;
        color: #4b4b4b;
        font-size: 14px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

.datePickerWrapper {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
 }

        .datePickerWrapper::before {
            content: "\f073";
            font-family: FontAwesome;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: normal;
            text-decoration: inherit;
            color: #717171;
            font-size: 18px;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #D8EEF3;
            
            padding: 0px 10px;
            right: 0px;
            cursor: pointer;
            height: 100%;
            border-left: 1px solid #717171;
            border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the background and border to the input element to simulate the needed effect:

```css
#datepicker {
  border: 1px solid #717171;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #4b4b4b;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background:
    linear-gradient(#717171,#717171) right 38px top 0 / 1px 100%,
    linear-gradient(#D8EEF3,#D8EEF3) right            /38px 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.datePickerWrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.datePickerWrapper::before {
  content: "\f073";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  color: #717171;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  right: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
<div class="datePickerWrapper"><input type="text" id="datepicker"></div>
```